# getting error in android

Tags: android

i have parsed data successfully using sax parser and output is coming properly in logcat but i have to arrange that data systematically. But the problem is my question length and index is 2 so options are also coming 2. instead they are 4 for each question. please suggest

code snippet is

```
for (int i = 0; i < categorylist.getTitle().size(); i++) {

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

            TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                  new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

            int leftMargin=0;
            int topMargin=2;
            int rightMargin=0;
            int bottomMargin=1;

            tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

            tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

            name[i]= new TextView(this);
            name[i].setText(categorylist.getTitle().get(i));
            name[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            name[i].setTextSize(12);
            name[i].setPadding(10,0,0,0);
            name[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(name[i]);
            t1.addView(tr, tableRowParams);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            rad1[i]= new RadioButton(this);
            rad1[i].setText(categorylist.getValue().get(i));    
            rad1[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            rad1[i].setTextSize(12);
            rad1[i].setPadding(10,0,0,0);
            rad1[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            rgrp.addView(rad1[i], 0, layoutParams);

        }
```

and xml is

```
<Values>
<Question>

<Description><![CDATA[Some Question]]></Description>

                    <Options>

                        <option value="correct"><![CDATA[All of these]]></option>

                        <option value="incorrect"><![CDATA[Ok]]></option>

                        <option value="incorrect"><![CDATA[Fine]]></option>

                        <option value="incorrect"><![CDATA[Good one]]></option>





                    </Options>  

            </Question>

</Values>
```

logcat output is:

```
05-14 15:22:27.228: INFO/This is the title:(559): Which of the following are called celestial bodies?
05-14 15:22:27.248: INFO/This is the option:(559): All of these
05-14 15:22:27.248: INFO/This is the option:(559): Sun
05-14 15:22:27.248: INFO/This is the option:(559): Planets
05-14 15:22:27.248: INFO/This is the option:(559): Moon 
05-14 15:22:27.258: INFO/This is the title:(559): In our solar system, _________ planets revolve around the Sun.
05-14 15:22:27.258: INFO/This is the option:(559): eight
05-14 15:22:27.258: INFO/This is the option:(559): five
05-14 15:22:27.258: INFO/This is the option:(559): ten
05-14 15:22:27.258: INFO/This is the option:(559): nine
```

Comment: please add a full logcat output to the question

Comment: SO If you know the options of every question is 4 then write 4 instead of size what is the Question

Comment: i tried that also. but it was throwing error. array out of bound exception.

Comment: Seriously stucked. I no i am doing silly mistake somewhere. but not getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You should have two loop for example

```
int l;
    for (int i = 0; i < categorylist.getTitle().size(); i++){
    for(int j= 0; j < optionlist.size()/categorylist.getTitle().size(); j++){
    //add option to question
l=l++;
//use l;
    }
    }
```

Comment: yeah now it is getting all 8 radio buttons but repeating 1st questions options for second also

Comment: check updated and accept the answer use updated because j always start from 0